# mercurial what causes multiple unwanted heads

Tags: mercurial

I'm working with another programmer and he keeps creating multiple heads in mercurial without knowing how it's happening. I can't seem to (remotely) debug the problem so I'm stuck wondering what could cause the automatic and silent creation of a second head.

hg merge fixes the problem but I'd like to stop this.

He's on a windows machine and I'm on linux and I activated the EolExtension.

We are using a central repo but it seems uninvolved.

Comment: See whether [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6927897/562459) is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

These are probably happening when a commit is performed from a revision that is not the tip (or the last revision of whatever branch you're working on, if using multiple named branches). This creates anonymous branches which must be merged. It's not uncommon and doesn't mean anything's necessarily broken. If these commits from further up the branch are intentional, then you'll just have to get used to merging heads. In order to avoid creating multiple heads, perform `hg pull -u` before committing (though you may still need to do some merging or syncing).

Comment: We are not using any branches at the moment. I think I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: You're always using branches. Multiple heads are anonymous branches. Different clones are anonymous branches. Your clone vs his clone are different anonymous branches. This is core to understanding Mercurial and how things like this occur.