# How can I make the current (non HEAD) revision the only HEAD of my branch

Tags: mercurial

I have:

1. Created a branch off a wrong branch and did some work
2. Created the branch off the correct branch, ending up with 2 HEADS
3. Did some work, merged them, only to realise I don't want one of the HEADS at all and want to go back to make an earlier revision the only HEAD.

[image: I want this to be the head]

How can I make my current revision (`mid 236`) the only HEAD of my branch in Mercurial?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial: How to deal with one branch that has two heads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927733/mercurial-how-to-deal-with-one-branch-that-has-two-heads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you have NOT pushed** (you commits still say draft) then:

Either remove the commits:

Use `hg strip` to remove changeset 67723 (and any parents you don't want)

Or just change the phrase of the unwanted commits from draft to secret, to prevent accidently pushing.

**If you have pushed then**:

1. update to 67723
2. close the branch. (Click the "Branch: b33814" label, select Close current branch) + then commit.
3. Update to 67655
4. do some work :).
5. commit.
   repeat step 4

Comment: Just to add - it is not technically required to strip the unwanted head nor to close the branch. Both may be good ideas just to "clean up" however.

Comment: Indeed. In fact for non pushed changes I often just change the phase to secret. I will update the answer. Thanks.